# Cannot get OpenGL 3.3 functions with QGLWidget (Linux)

Tags: linux, qt, opengl, glew

I'm heaving a very strange problem, so I've written a minimal example to reproduce it.

First I derive a class from `QGLWidget`:

```
class Demo : public QGLWidget
{
public:
    struct error {};

    explicit Demo( const QGLFormat& format ) : QGLWidget( format )
    {
    }

protected:
    virtual void initializeGL() override
    {
        const GLenum glewState = glewInit();
        if( glewState != GLEW_OK ) throw error();
        unsigned int id;
        glGenSamplers( 1, &id ); //<-- Note this here!
    }
};
```

And here is the `main` function:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );
    QGLFormat format = QGLFormat::defaultFormat();
    format.setVersion( 3, 3 );
    Demo demo( format );
    demo.show();
    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

I build this code with G++ 4.9. When I run it with GDB, here is what I get:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000402add in Demo::initializeGL() () at test.cpp:16
...
```

Obviously the function `glGenSamplers` points to `0`. I have also added another line

```
if( glGenSamplers == nullptr ) throw error();
```

to verify this, and yes, the error is raised here. But why? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to force the `QGLWidget` to compatibility profile:

```
format.setProfile( QGLFormat::Compatibility );
```

Although I do not understand why `glGenSamplers` requires this. As far as I understand this function should actually be part of the core profile since 3.3.

Comment: That is not the real issue here. You hit a well-known GLEW bug (which the maintainers refuse to fix since years). GLEW does not work correctly in core profile. You can set `glewExperimental=GL_TRUE;` before `glewInit()` as a workaround. However, this has some other issues. In the end, it mght best to just drop GLEW and use some other extension loader, like glLoadGen or glad.